# How multi tasking is achieved when same method is executed?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, multiprocessing

I have learnt that when an object is instantiated, memory is allocated only for the variables defined in the class and only a single copy of method exists in the method area of JVM. i.e. when a particular method is called from any object, the same lines of code(with different local variable on stack of each object) is run. Now, I'm not able to understand how true multi tasking is achieved in the following scenario where we have a multi core processor and there are threads running SIMULTANEOUSLY on all cores and they make same method call in a class. Though each thread contains distinct stack areas, as there is only one copy of method residing in the memory,they cant read the lines of code simultaneously right, as there exists only one memory bus to fetch the instruction? Then, how is multi tasking achieved in true sense?

Comment: "they cant read the lines of code simultaneously right" As you have worked out, if this were the case, multi-threading wouldn't work, so this has to be wrong doesn't it? You seems to have answered your own question. If it doesn't make sense it is probably wrong.

Comment: You and your friend are watching a movie with subtitles. If one only one of you could see the subtitles, then the other one couldn't understand what is going on. But not only is that a bad idea it's harder to achieve than everyone watching the movie being able to read the subtitles.

Comment: When I learned computer architecture many years ago, it was true that a given memory chip (of which there may be a number in a computer) could only serve one CPU core at a time, but did it so fast that the CPU cores didn’t experience any waiting time. If this is still true, it would be true no matter if the cores are performing the same code or different code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ,Could you please explain vividly? I could not understand your second comment.

Comment: @AnilVedala it's an analogy. There is nothing to prevent two CPUs reading the same memory, but you start with the idea that this is not possible and then conclude it wouldn't work, but since it does work your premise must be wrong. So it's not clear what you are asking that you don't know already..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But, Please help me understand how can two cpus/cores access same memory at the same TIME when we have only one memory bus. Ofcourse, one other way this is possible is by storing those instructions in caches(L1, L2) that cores have.

Comment: @Ole V.V.: the main memory chips of most computers (there are exceptions) can only serve one request at a time, but CPU cores have dedicated local caches, further, the CPU usually also has a shared cache that serves the local caches, so if multiple cores want the same data, it’s fetched from main memory into the shared cache only once and then distributed to the core local caches from there. But if the cores need different not-cached-yet data from the same main memory chip, the chip’s speed becomes an issue, including the possibility that the core *have* to wait.

Comment: Thanks for deeper explanation, @Holger, it all makes sense to me. I hope and think it does to the OP too.